# Using VueScan in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, scanner, laserjet

I just finished setting up my HP LaserJet Professional M1212nf MFP on Ubuntu wirelessly (IPV4 address). In terms of scanning, it works properly with Xsane and simple-scan.

But VueScan 9.5.53 (x64) doesn't detect it. I installed it manually from the VueScan website's tarball. Whenever I select the 'Scan' option, I get this message:

> VueScan didn't find a scanner connected to your computer.
>
> 1) Make sure the scanner is plugged in and turned on before you run VueScan.
>
> 2) If you have a USB scanner, try a different USB cable and/or a different USB port.
>
> 3) If you have a WiFi scanner, make sure your firewall isn't blocking responses from the scanner.
>
> 4) If the scanner has a locking switch, make sure it's in the unlocked position.
>
> 5) Try turning your scanner off and back on.
>
> 6) If you have a USB scanner, try running VueScan as root to see if it's a libusb device protection problem.
>
> Then exit VueScan and run it again.
>
> The supported scanners list has more useful information about your scanner. Would you like to see this?

This message appears even when I have the printer's USB plugged into my computer, and even when I run sudo ~/Desktop/VueScan and then try wirelessly scanning or scanning with the printer's USB plugged in.

Did I install VueScan the wrong way? I used the 'tar xvf' method to extract it to my Home folder. There's a hidden folder (.vuescan) in there with an .ini and .log file.

The .log file (vuescan.log):

```
    VueScan 9 x64 (9.5.53) Aug  1 2016 UTC-5 Linux gcc 4 8 cpus
Unregistered
    0 Calling prob_open
    0 Found device: vid 1d6b pid 0003 por 001
    0 Found device: vid 046d pid c51b por 013
    0 Found device: vid 1d6b pid 0002 por 001
    0 Found device: vid 8087 pid 0024 por 002
    0 Found device: vid 1d6b pid 0002 por 001
    0 Found device: vid 147e pid 2016 por 003
    0 Found device: vid 8087 pid 0024 por 002
    0 Found device: vid 1d6b pid 0002 por 001
    1 Searching for SCSI devices
    1 Found device: /dev/sg0
    1 Calling net1_open
    1 Calling usbi_open
    1 Calling dot4_open
    1 Calling scsi_init
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0000 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0001 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0002 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0003 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0004 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0005 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0006 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0007 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0100 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0101 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0102 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0103 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0104 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0105 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0106 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0107 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0200 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0201 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0202 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0203 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0204 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0205 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0206 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0207 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0300 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0301 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0302 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0303 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0304 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0305 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0306 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0307 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0400 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0401 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0402 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0403 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0404 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0405 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0406 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0407 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0500 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0501 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0502 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0503 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0504 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0505 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0506 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0507 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0600 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0601 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0602 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0603 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0604 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0605 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0606 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0607 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0700 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0701 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0702 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0703 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0704 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0705 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0706 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0707 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0800 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0801 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0802 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0803 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0804 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0805 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0806 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0807 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0900 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0901 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0902 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0903 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0904 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0905 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0906 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0907 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a00 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a01 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a02 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a03 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a04 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a05 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a06 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0a07 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b00 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b01 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b02 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b03 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b04 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b05 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b06 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0b07 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c00 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c01 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c02 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c03 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c04 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c05 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c06 
    2    0 INQUIRY                   12  0  0  0 24  0                   80000004 0c07 
    2 Changed Prefs  | Language                   0                      1
    2 Changed Prefs  | Startup tip                1                      0
    2 Changed Prefs  | Window x offset           -1                    138
    2 Changed Prefs  | Window y offset           -1                     53
    2 Changed Prefs  | Window x size            640                   1462
    2 Changed Prefs  | Window y size            480                    876
    2 Changed Color  | Color balance              7                      2
    2 **** Menu Help | About
    6 Calling scsi_term
    6 Calling dot4_clos
    6 Calling usbi_clos
    6 Exiting scsi_clos
  595 Calling scsi_term
  595 Calling dot4_clos
  595 Calling usbi_clos
  595 Exiting scsi_clos
  595 Calling prob_clos
```

What should I do to get VueScan to recognize my printer? It's definitely supported by VueScan, because I use VueScan on Windows computers with the same printer/scanner combo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. From http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=1659

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 132b:0012 Konica Minolta Dimage Scan Elite 5400 II (2892)
```

Add a ‘.rules’ file under the /etc/udev/rules.d directory (not the one at /lib/udev/rules.d!)

Create a text file, i.e.: ‘50-scanner.rules‘ with the following contents, including the vendor and product ids from the # lsusb output:

```
# Minolta Dimage 5400 II (added Feb 2016. RG)
ATTRS{idVendor}=="132b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0012", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes", GROUP="scanner", MODE="0660"
```

Create a new ‘scanner‘ group and add yourself to it. Then, log out/in and power-cycle the scanner, and everything should work correctly..

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for USB connectivity, but not wireless:

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/scanner-worked-in-15-10-does-not-work-in-16-04/4761

FWIW, I have the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 when everything worked fine on 15.10 with my Brother MFC-J485DW. However, the only reason I used VueScan in the first place was that I couldn't get Simple Scan or XSane to work over the network for some reason. However, I've gotten both to work with the Brother drivers on 16.04 installed via the "Driver Install Tool" downloaded from the Brother website. Just make sure you set up your scanner with a static IP address (I used the router configuration with a static DHCP lease to do this) and you should be good to go. Granted, this doesn't *really* answer your original question (or mine), but it provides two alternatives, hopefully.

Comment: please copy, write up the essential parts here.

Answer (score -1):

> The following is the translated version of this message, from Google Translate.  The original non-English answer is available in the revision history.

First on the router, you must assign a fixed IP to your multifunction printer. Once this is done, you need to open the firewall ports on your PC.
Open the terminal and enter the following rule:
"sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" without the quotes.
Where in place of the X you have to put the real IP of your multifunction printer.
Now vuescan will work.
Then to delete the rule always from terminal type:
"sudo ufw delete allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"